# How should I pass static data into a React component?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, webpack

I’m working on taking several pieces of an existing site and making them bundled components with Webpack and React. The existing site doesn’t use any kind of an API and outputs most of its markup with PHP.

My first project is to take a form that’s used in several places on the site and move it into a React component. This form is sometimes pre-populated with data from the database, and I'm not sure of the cleanest way to get that data into the React component.

Previously the form was just output with PHP and several `<?php echo $FormFieldValue ?>` blocks. I need to get that PHP data into the React component.

Currently I'm doing it this way:

**In the PHP I’m creating an array that represents what I might get from an API:**

```
<?php
    $formData = array(
        'FirstName' => $theUser->FirstName,
        'LastName' => $theUser->LastName,
        'EmailAddress' => $theUser->EmailAddress,
        'Company' => $theUser->Company
    );
?>
```

**Then I convert that to JSON in a data- attribute on the $el the React component is injected into:**

```
<div data-props='<?php echo json_encode($billingInfoFormData) ?>'></div>
```

**My component:**

```
var BillingInfo = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return this.props.dataProps
    },
    render() { … }
})
```

**And finally, to render it:**

```
var $domEl = $('[data-billing-info-form]')
var BillingInfoForm = require('./components/Forms/BillingInfo.jsx')
var BillingInfoFormDom = React.render(
    <BillingInfoForm
        dataProps = {$domEl.data('props')}
        formTitle = 'Billing Info' />,
    $domEl.get(0)
)
```

Now here's the thing. I know populating state with props is considered a no-no. So I'm here, turning to Stack Overflow to see what my options are.

Suggestions??

Comment: Why not just store the data needed in a `<script>` tag as a "global" variable set to the JSON value from `$billingInfoFormData` and read it into the `BillingInfoForm`? I don't understand why you're putting the data into a `div`?

Comment: Primarily because I didn't want to store data in the global namespace without immediately attaching it to something explicitly.

Comment: Well, it's how most of the isomorphic React applications are implemented. So, it's a very common pattern (and it's common with other frameworks and libraries as well).

Comment: [Props in getInitialState Is an Anti-Pattern](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html)

Comment: Ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use calls in react rendering, that is not a good idea. Use php for api calls only and let a javascript framework like [SuperAgent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) do ajax request towards RESTfull services and pass it back into a javascript framework called [RefluxJS[2](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs).

With [RefluxJS](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs) you have access to cool things like "stores" for data that any component can access or define actions for event listeners, to notify every component there is a change in the data "store"

This will indirect solve your question about passing data between and into components.

---

To awnser your question, look at the code below.

```
//set default props
getDefaultProps() {
    return {
        dataProps: {}
    }
},

//access object like this
this.props.dataProps
```

Comment: This is an existing site with no API, though, and no means of building one. So the data must come from the page the component appears on, in JSON format.

Comment: i advise you not to use PHP in react rendering, same as using javascript in PHP classes.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<div id="root">
    <script type="text/json">
        { "data": [] }
    </script>
</div>

var root = document.getElementByID( 'root' )
var data = JSON.parse( root.firstElementChild.innerHTML )
React.render( <Component data={data} />, root )
```